# Why once a sql has read timed out, then subsequent query always slow

Tags: oracle, mybatis

There is a scheduler task(used `mybatis`), every 10 min get changed records from latest execution time to current time then sync these records to elasticsearch, but from 2020-07-09 14:00:00 the query sql met `Socket read timed out` and from that time all subsequent sql are all read timed out, but till 2020-07-17 I found the problem, at first I thought maybe the time range is too long, so the sql is still timed out, so I updated the start time to 10 min ago, then reboot the app, though resolved timed out, but the sql is very slow, need 5 min, but I execute the sql at `Oracle SQL Developer` it's not slow, then I execute the sql at the same server in `sqlplus` console, still not slow, So I suspect it's oracle server problem, maybe it has remembered the sql which has too many socket read timed out, cause following query still slow. Then I tried to changed the sql in my app(a union b union c ==> b union c union a), the restart the app, this time the changed sql is not slow.

So why once a sql has (maybe many) timed out, then following query still slow （even if reduced time range）but changed the sql appearance it could back to normal?

Comment: Are you sure the query executed by mybatis is 100% exact as the manual execution?  Could be different parameter binding.  take a look in v$sqlarea to see query performance

Comment: @OldProgrammer Because manual execution is normal, but app is slow, so I suspect maybe change the sql could help and indeed it is. It has nothing to do with parameter binding (update_time between #{startTime} and #{endTime}) , as the same binding manual execution is normal but app is slow